# Speed up item adding to list

Tags: vb.net

I wan't to combine two lists of string, both of them have 200000+ items in them. Here's the code I'm using to combine them:

```
For Each item in list2
   list1.add(item)
Next
```

But the problem is that it takes ages to add each item from list2 to list1. So I'm asking, is there any better solution to combine these lists?

Comment: Better solution would be not to have 400,000 strings in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too wonder at the need, but if you need them consider using StringBuilder.  I ran a little test:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, _
                          e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stpw1 As New Stopwatch
    Dim stpw2 As New Stopwatch

    'sample data
    Dim ipsumA() As String = New String() {"Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", _
                                           "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", _
                                           "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", _
                                           "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", _
                                           "et", "dolore", "magna", "aliqua", "Ut", _
                                           "enim", "ad", "minim", "veniam", "quis", _
                                           "nostrud", "exercitation", "ullamco", _
                                           "laboris", "nisi", "ut", "aliquip", "ex", _
                                           "ea", "commodo", "consequat", "Duis", "aute", _
                                           "irure", "dolor", "in", "reprehenderit", "in", _
                                           "voluptate", "velit", "esse", "cillum", "dolore", _
                                           "eu", "fugiat", "nulla", "pariatur", "Excepteur", _
                                           "sint", "occaecat", "cupidatat", "non", "proident", _
                                           "sunt", "in", "culpa", "qui", "officia", "deserunt", _
                                           "mollit", "anim", "id", "est", "laborum"}

    Dim list1 As New List(Of System.Text.StringBuilder)
    Dim list2 As New List(Of System.Text.StringBuilder)
    Debug.WriteLine("Approx. 200,000+ strings per list")
    stpw2.Restart()
    stpw1.Restart()
    Do While list1.Count < 200000
        For Each s As String In ipsumA
            list1.Add(New System.Text.StringBuilder(s))
            list2.Add(New System.Text.StringBuilder(s))
        Next
    Loop
    stpw1.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine(stpw1.Elapsed.ToString)

    stpw1.Restart()
    list1.AddRange(list2)
    stpw1.Stop()
    stpw2.Stop()

    Debug.WriteLine(stpw1.Elapsed.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(stpw2.Elapsed.ToString)
End Sub
```

It took about .3 seconds, for what it is worth.

Answer (score 5):

There is a built-in method in `List` class that does exactly what you need:

```
list1.AddRange(list2)
```

Take a look at Microsoft page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/z883w3dc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y631) to see some other info.
Anyway, are you really sure you need to have so many strings in memory?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the approximate maximum size of a list in advance, then specify it in the constructor. `List<T>` uses an array internally to hold the items. It has an original size of 4 items if don't specify a size. If it is full, then a new array with the double size is created and the content of the old array is copied to the new array. This happens many times for 400000 items!

```
var list1 = new List<string>(500000);
```